# Create external link containing Mturk "workerId" but called "participant_label" in Turkprime(Cloudresearch)

Tags: mechanicalturk, otree, mturk

I am using oTree and want to publish my MTurk experiment with Turkprime (Cloudresearch).

I want the external link to contain the Mturk `workerId`
. However, I want the `workerId` be called `participant_label`.

How is that possible?

I already tried

`https://www.example.com/room/room2/?particpant_label=workerId`
`https://www.example.com/room/room2/?particpant_label=?workerId`
`https://www.example.com/room/room2/?particpant_label=WORKERID`

Comment: you can see how I deal with Cloudresearch ids here: https://github.com/chapkovski/cloudtester/blob/main/cloudcapturer/views.py

Comment: That looks amazing. Thank you. Could you maybe also specify how to implement that correctly?

Comment: This code for each session in oTree creates an 'entrance' url for cloud workers. looking like: www. your_web_site.com/cloud/SESSION_CODE. (of course SESSION_CODE and web_site_name are yours). and you plug this link to the cloudresearch template, and when they access it it correctly passes all the params back to oTree

Comment: The redirecting works perfectly! Thank you so much for the code and the clarification. I just copied the app into my project and added `EXTENSION_APPS = ['cloudcapturer']` to my settings. However, cookies are still set when opening the link. Did I miss something in the code that unsets cookies or is that not possible?

Comment: Why do you want to unset them?

Comment: I promised our ethics committee to avoid cookies.

Comment: I’m from the phone now, so can’t immediately provide a solution but as far as I remember you just need to switch off csrf and change the middleware from SessionMiddlrware

Comment: I think the simplest would be to use a no_cookies decorator for the parent Page in otree from here: https://pypi.org/project/django-cookieless/

Comment: I must admit that I'm a bit too noobie to solve that on my own. But it's a good idea to split the question into two different ones. Thank you so much for everything, Philipp. The second part of the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969643/disable-all-cookies-in-otree