# Disable all cookies in oTree

Tags: cookies, otree

In oTree, two cookies are created:
`sessionId` and `csrf_token`.

I want to disable both; however, I don't know how to do that.

I know that when I use `participant_label` in the URL, I can avoid the `sessionId`-cookie. However, then I still have the `csrf_token`-cookie.

Do you know how to unset it? I heard that [django-cookieless](http://pypi.org/project/django-cookieless) should be a solution, but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a bit untrivial.
For injecting `csrftoken` in Django (which oTree is based on) they use `CsrfViewMiddleware`. So if it *would be* a normal Django project you would just delete  `CsrfViewMiddleware` from `MIDDLWARE` param in your `settings.py`. But unfortunately oTree usually does the things in a very peculiar way that can drive crazy most of the people and to do this you need a bit of work.

This work consists of two parts:

1. write your own middleware that will manually delete all the cookies from any request.
2. Manually delete `CsrfViewMiddleware` after your app starts. You may ask 'why the first part wouldn't be enough? Because apparently CsrfViewMiddleware kicks in after your middleware, and it will still inject a cookie even if you manually delete it. You may ask why you need (1) if we do (2) - I do not know the answer for sure, but I suspect that oTree in addition injects some other cookies (including csrf), so if you just delete CsrfViewMiddleware that's not enough (I can be wrong).

Anyway. **Part 1. Writing your own middleware**

1. You create a python file in one of your apps, let's say `middle.py`.
   You write there something like:

```py
class DisableCSRFMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        for cookie in request.COOKIES:
            response.delete_cookie(cookie)
        return response
```

and in your `settings.py` you register your middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = ['myapp.middle.DisableCSRFMiddleware']
```

where `myapp` of course should be a name of your app, and `middle` is just a name of your file there

**part 2. Manually removing `CsrfViewMiddleware`**

1. In any your oTree app there should be a file named `__init__.py`
   Go there and insert this:

```
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

2. Create in your app (`myapp`) a file named `apps.py` and insert there this stuff:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        middleware = settings.MIDDLEWARE
        settings.MIDDLEWARE = [i for i in middleware if i != 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' ]
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your well-described code. Especially telling me to where exactly put the code was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Philipp can be adjusted to delete cookies only on the participant's PCs. Then, the admin-interface will still use cookies.

In middle.py:

```
import re
class DisableCSRFMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)

        pattern = re.compile("/p/")
        if pattern.search(request.META["PATH_INFO"]):
            for cookie in request.COOKIES:
                response.delete_cookie(cookie)
            return response
        else:
            return response
```